# How does Geordi not recognize a beard?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

In "The Schizoid Man," Data invites Geordi and Deanna to his quarters to ask their opinions of his beard. Geordi asks Data if he has damaged his face.

How can Geordi not recognize what a beard looks like? Commander Riker has a beard. Perhaps synthetic beards appear differently to Geordi than real ones.

Comment: "*A subplot in Tormé’s script involved Data’s lack of ego; trimmed along with several of the scenes featuring Data’s beard was the original tag scene-already a legendary TNG story—in which he is seen trying yet again to emulate an admired and respected crew member. In this scene, to Picard’s chagrin, the android is bald.*"

Comment: @Valorum Where is the cool quote from?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - The Star Trek Companion (2nd Edition)

Comment: Geordi's comment doesn't necessarily imply that he doesn't recognise a beard. Perhaps he was just teasing Data (which reminds me of some of the disparaging remarks characters make to Wodehouse's Bertie Wooster when he tries to grow a moustache), or it could be that Geordi was wondering if the beard was to cover something up (for example, in The Life and Death of Colonel Blimp the titular character grows a moustache to hide a duelling scar).

Comment: I find the premise of this question ridiculous and I'm surprised by the upvotes.   At the very least, it should be giving the quote of what he actually said and asking about why be said that.   Clearly Geordi not recognizing a beard is preposterous.

Comment: It shouldn't be interpreted as "what is this stuff on your face?", it should be interpreted as "*why* is there hair on your face?"

Comment: @Martha:   Yes, well put.

Comment: I think you're wrong, Pop. Look at Geordi's face when Data tells him it's a beard. Either La Forge is a good actor, or he was genuinely surprised at Data's revelation.

Comment: @HamSandwich:   With all due respect, in your comments here and below my answer, you are just continually asserting your premise and your interpretation, which I indicated is simply not the case and have given the other intended interpretations.   Just ignoring that and keeping your same position while trying to start some kind of debate makes not sense.    If you don't like my answer, you can downvote it and choose not to accept it.   But there's nothing more to say.

Comment: I am free to my opinion. And your interpretation of this scene is your opinion.

Comment: There is also the fact that Data was facing the mirror and had his back to Geordi, Geordi was viewing him through a mirror. A large amount of the EM spectrum is not reflected by a mirror. So Its possible that he was only seeing part of the reflection rather than the full EM range he normally sees Data in. Its the first time he has looked at Data in a reflection of (mostly) visible light only. How often have you seen close friends reflection in a mirror, the visor would make that very confusing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The full transcript is:

> (They go through to the inner room, and we see Data's reflection in a full length mirror. He is sporting a full set, a beard like Riker's) 
>   LAFORGE: Did you damage your face, Data? 
>   DATA: It is a beard, Geordi. A fine, full, dignified beard. One which commands respect and projects thoughtfulness and dignity. Well? Opinions? 
>   TROI: It's er, very different. 
>   DATA: When I stroke the beard thusly, do I not appear more intellectual? 
>   TROI: I'm sorry, I have to go now. Goodbye. 
>   (Troi leaves, quickly, laughing) 
>   DATA: Why was she laughing?

It is clearly not the case that Geordi doesn't recognize a beard when he sees one.   Obviously the entire scene is played somewhat for comic effect.   The comment by Geordi can be understood as some combination of:

- Rhetorical remark for comedic effect
- Geordi probably didn't think Data was capable of growing a beard
- Geordi may be guessing that the beard is simply applied to his face (not grown), which is likely. (But how exactly does Data's hair work to begin with?)
- Geordi guesses that he may have applied it to cover up damage to his skin. (One assumes that it's easier to glue on a beard than to fix his integument.)
- Geordi doesn't know what Data's motivation is (which Data then explains)

Bottom line:   You're stretching too far.   It's not that complicated and doesn't required an exotic explanation about why Geordi doesn't recognize beards.   To quote @Martha:  *It shouldn't be interpreted as "what is this stuff on your face?", it should be interpreted as "why is there hair on your face?"*

Comment: "Got some dirt on yer lip, there" - Said to every teen growing their first mustache evah.

Comment: Since when does hair grow on Data's face when he damages it? Perhaps it was said for comedic effect. I don't think I'm stretching too far, though.

Comment: It's not that it grew there. Geordi sees the beard and the only logical reason he can come up with for the absurd scene in front of him is that Data applied it to cover up damage. Similar to how one might see a coworker suddenly start wearing hats ALL THE TIME and make the guess that something happened to their hair.

Comment: I guess. But Data doesn’t care what others think of him, so that seems to be a stretch.

Comment: @HamSandwich:   Clearly he does.   It's right there in the transcript.   "Do I not appear more intellectual?"   He is exploring personal appearance and perception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.